# Why is "else" a special symbol in scheme? Can it be defined as a procedure?

Tags: lisp, scheme

I started learning Scheme recently by reading SICP. In the opening chapter, it goes over conditionals and it talks about using `else` within the `cond` "special form" - which to my understanding is defined as "something the interpreter "just knows about". My question, is why is `else` defined as a "special form" and not as a procedure?

If I fire up my mit-scheme interpreter, and type: `(else 1)` it raises an error. If I define something like `(define (myelse x) x)`, I can use it in the same way it is used within the `cond` expression like:

```
(define (abs x)
    (cond ((< x 0) (- x))
        (myelse x)))
```

So why is `else` treated as something special, and not defined in scheme itself?

Comment: `(myelse x)` inside your `cond` does not do what you think it does. It doesn't call `myelse` function. As part of `cond` evaluation, if `x` is not negative, `myelse` value is checked for being false (`#f`), and since it's not, the rest of forms in that clause are evaluated and last value (i.e. `x`) is returned. To see this, redefine `(define (myelse x) 42)` and call `(abs 7)`. You will get back `7`, not `42`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it were an ordinary variable, you could do:

```
(set! else #f)
```

and then all the `cond` expressions that depend on the `else` clause being executed would stop working.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is why I love this community. Being unfamiliar with Scheme I had to look up what set! and #f meant, but I can see your point now. It would globally redefine `else` to boolean false.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that all that this requires is that `cond` understand that when the symbol `else` is used as a test for in a clause, it means the same thing as `#t`.  It's just a syntactic issue;  `else` could still be used in other places just like any other identifier.  Indeed, in DrRacket with language R5RS, I can do: 
`(let ((else #f))
  (cond 
    ((= 2 3) 'two-is-three)
    (else 'two-is-not-three)
    (#t 'default)))` and I get the `default` as the result.

Comment: On top of that, if the `else` clause is in the final position (which is actually the only case in which, according to R5RS, `else` should be treated specially), `(let ((else #f))
  (display (cond 
    ((= 2 3) 'two-is-three)
    (else 'two-is-not-three))))` prints `#<void>`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor How the different implementations behave is unpredictable if the symbol `else` was bound to something. E.g. `(let ((else #f)) (cond (else 1) (#t 2)))` isn't accepted in Gambit since `else` can only be in the last clause. Also your last example prints two-is-not-three since else in a cond is else and not any bound variable.

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered and old but... a better answer, in my opinion, would be: **else** is a keyword in Scheme. Languages that do not work over keywords (*latu sensu*), like TeX, let you redefining any word (~identifier) in a script , including *if* and *else* (in TeX terminology, \if and \else). But in Scheme (and in a lot of other languages like C and Phyton) else keyword rules important things at the core of the compiler/interpreter text program, i. e., determined at compile time of them. So such redefinition is impracticable.

http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-keywords
[http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_idx_108](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%25_idx_108)